# Can I change my megastone accessory?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

After you receive the megastone in the ring (Mega Ring), **is there a way to be able to change the accessory the stone is in?**

It appears that Korrina has a Mega Glove and Diantha has something different, I believe it's a Mega Charm, so that leads one to speculate there could possibly be other accessories for you to equip your megastone.

**If** this is possible, how does one acquire the different accessories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is (sadly) not a thing that is possible. You are given the Mega Ring, and that is what you are stuck with. While it would seem that the [Key Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Ring) is the important bit and it can be set in a number of things (bracelet, glove, and necklace have been seen to be used), there is no mechanism in-game to allow for this.